# How to return a list of items from a different py file

Tags: python

I have 2 .py files (data.py, access.py)

In **access.py**, I have a few strings:

```
Japan = ['brown', 'cow', 'around']
Korea = ['black', 'chicken', '344']
China = ['grey', '3411', 'leaf']
Indonesia = ['red', 'green', '']
```

In **data.py**, I have a module:

```
def whichcolour(country)
       print("access + country[1]")  # Doesn't work
```

**My Results**

What I am trying to achieve is, to run `whichcolour` through `data.py` and it will return/ print out whatever is in that list.

I know `print(access.Japan[1])` works.. It returns `cow`.

How should the `print` statement be written such that it gives me the same result?

Comment: `print("access + {}".format(country[1]))`, considering that `country` is actually a list.

Comment: Use: `"access " + country[1]`

Comment: Don't store the country info like that in `access.py`: use a dictionary with the key as the country name and the value as the list.  That will be much simpler and easier to expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

access.py

```
countries = {
    'Japan': ['brown', 'cow', 'around'],
    'Korea': ['black', 'chicken', '344'],
    'China': ['grey', '3411', 'leaf'],
    'Indonesia': ['red', 'green', '']
}
```

data.py

```
from access import countries

def whichcolour(country, countries):
    print('{} has the color {}'.format(country, countries[country][0]))

for country in countries:
    whichcolour(country, countries)
```

output:

```
Japan has the color brown
Korea has the color black
China has the color grey
Indonesia has the color red
```

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do (there are two colors for Indonesia) but this should get you started.

Comment: Speaking of dictionaries, why not just use JSON altogether?

Comment: @EddoHintoso Or just a nested dictionary, such that you could access `countries['Japan']['color']`. I don't know what names would be suitable as keys for the other values, so I leave that for the OP.

Comment: Fair enough. The answer would be better if you explained that Python (along with many other languages) operate with zero-based indexing. It was why the OP failed to access the color element by accidentally selecting the 2nd element.

Comment: I'm not too sure what JSON is.. I'm still really new to python. But this code that @timgeb wrote works! Thanks

Comment: @jakewong also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python